# How can I Unit Test GraphQL file Upload with API Platform?

Tags: symfony, graphql, phpunit, api-platform.com

In addition to my other tests against my GraphQL API Platform backend, I am attempting to test file uploads.  I'm not quite sure whether the `ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Client` class has the ability to facilitate this test, or if `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` should be used to provide the test file as it is for a REST operation.

Here is roughly where I am at in terms of putting together this test. (With some irrelevant parts removed for  simplification)

```php
 public function testCreateMediaObject(): void {
    $file = new UploadedFile('fixtures/files/logo.png', 'logo.png');
    $client = self::createClient();

    $gql = <<<GQL
    mutation UploadMediaObject(\$file: Upload!) {
      uploadMediaObject(input: {file: \$file}) {
        mediaObject {
          id
          contentUrl
        }
      }
    }
    GQL;

    $response = $client->request('POST', '/api/graphql', [
      'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
      'json' => [
        'query' => $gql,
        'variables' => ["file" => null],
        'map' => ['0' => ['variables.file']],
        '0' => $file,
      ]
    ]);
    dd($response);

  }
```

The response I get seems to indicate that the file isn't being included as expected. Something like...

```
Variable "$file" of non-null type "Upload!" must not be null.
```

Or.. if I try to attach the file by simply assigning it directly in the `variables` property...

```
    $response = $client->request('POST', '/api/graphql', [
      'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
      'json' => [
        'query' => $gql,
        'variables' => ["file" => $file],
      ]
    ]);
```

then...

```
Variable "$file" got invalid value []; Expected type Upload; Could not get uploaded file, be sure to conform to GraphQL multipart request specification. Instead got: []
```

In my most recent attempt, I changed things up quite a bit after sifting through the graphql code...

```php
    $formFields = [
      'operations' => '{ "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) { uploadMediaObject(input: {file: $file}) { mediaObject { id contentUrl } } }", "variables": { "file": null } }',
      'map' => "{'0': ['variables.file']}",
      '0' => DataPart::fromPath(__DIR__.'/../../fixtures/files/logo.png'),
    ];
    $formData = new FormDataPart($formFields);
    $response = $client->request('POST', '/api/graphql', [
      'headers' => $formData->getPreparedHeaders()->toArray(),
      'body' => $formData->bodyToString(),
    ]);
```

The problem with this last attempt is that the server isn't seeing any  body parameters. So I receiving the exception

```
'GraphQL multipart request does not respect the specification.'
```

Which is found in `/api-platform/core/src/GraphQl/Action/EntrypointAction.php` within the `parseMultipartRequest` method.

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec

Comment: Thanks, I have consulted this spec, and am able to successfully use the media upload functionality using cURL, etc. The question is more about how this can be done in a functional test, with the provided `Client`.

Comment: done with curl ... then you should know what is wrong ... content-type, formData etc.

Comment: Appreciate the vote of confidence! ;)

Comment: So in the first scenario you had `["file" => null]`, in the second scenario you had something different (but didn't show the code), right? Perhaps you should make that visible what you did in the second scenario with `["file" => null]` in your question.

Comment: More information added, along with another recent attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few hours of debugging I found this solution:

```
$formData = new FormDataPart();
$file = new UploadedFile('src/DataFixtures/files/test.txt', 'test.txt');
    
$response = $this->$client->request('POST', 'api/graphql', [
    'headers' => $formData->getPreparedHeaders()->toArray(),
    'extra' => [
        'parameters' => [
            'operations' => '{ "query": "mutation UploadMediaObject($file: Upload!) { uploadMediaObject(input: {file: $file}) { mediaObject { id contentUrl } } }", "variables": { "file": null } }',
            'map' => '{ "0": ["variables.file"] }',
            '0' => @$file,
        ],
        'files' => [
            $file,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Refrence:

- https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec
- https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/

Comment: You nailed it @Dario!  Thanks!